# how to stop playing a screencast.com video embedded in a site through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a screencast video to my website.Now i want to stop the video  when i click on a button.I tried some javascript code onclick event over the button.

var myVideoPlayer = document.getElementById("playerId"); //gets video player
 myVideoPlayer.sendEvent("STOP");

But It didn't worked.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should check screencast documentation to see if they are providing an api for controlling the video.

If they don't, you can just remove the element from the DOM.

```
var myVideoPlayer = document.getElementById("playerId");
myVideoPlayer.parentNode.removeChild(myVideoPlayer );
```

If you need to bring it back, just create a new element with the player. If there is no API, you probably can't set it to a certain second in the video

Comment: Thanks @Moshe Shaham.I cannot find any api documentation.But i will try to implement  alternative solution which you suggested.                                                             cheers